# CQL get dynamic column value

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have C* 2.1.9 cluster. For it management I used thrift based driver. Also I have table `users` with `notes` dynamic created column in it. I can sure that with column really exists by `cassandra-cli`:

```
    list users

    RowKey: bla-bla
    ...
    => (name=notes, value=bla-bla, timestamp=bla-bla)
    ...
```

I want to get with dynamic column value using CQL. But static CQL schema knows nothing about this column. For example:

```
SELECT notes FROM users;

SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'notes' (SELECT [notes]...)">
```

How can I get value of this dynamic column using CQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added new column to my table and all work now!

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD notes text
```